# Generate Oracle SQL file as a result of query request

Tags: sql, oracle, export

I'm using a shell script to call Oracle sqlplus and I want to export the result of a query to an sql file.

This request give me a lot of values:

```
SELECT * FROM CUST_TABLE WHERE  CUST_CITY = 'San Fran';
```

And I want my script to generate an sql file like this:

```
evariste@Unix-Server$cat first_query_result.sql

INSERT INTO CUST_TABLE (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ....)
VALUES (CUST1_COLUMN_1, CUST1_COLUMN_2, ...);
INSERT INTO CUST_TABLE (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ....)
VALUES (CUST2_COLUMN_1, CUST2_COLUMN_2, ...);
INSERT INTO CUST_TABLE (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ....)
VALUES (CUST3_COLUMN_1, CUST3_COLUMN_2, ...);
```

Any idea (I have a little background in Oracle and SQL) on how to perform that in my script?

Comment: Take out the WITH clause (the first two lines in your example) altogether, and try that.

Comment: Read about the WITH clause (aka, subquery factoring) here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php

Comment: Got this error : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: You need extra quotes around `||username||`, i.e. `... VALUES('''||username||''','''||city||''');'...`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: Thanks, but still got this error : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Sorry i was missing a semi column :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
sqlplus -silent uid/pw@db <<+EOF
set heading off
set feedback off
set pagesize 0
set linesize 32000
set trimspool on
set termout off
set echo off
set verify off
set sqlblanklines off
spool somefile.sql
WITH cust_table AS 
(SELECT 1 id, 'San Francisco' city, 'C1V1' col1, 'C2V1' col2 FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Los Angeles', 'C1V2', 'C2V2' FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'San Jose', 'C1V3', 'C2V3' FROM dual
 UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'San Francisco', 'C1V4', 'C2V4' FROM dual)
SELECT 'INSERT INTO cust_table (id, city, col1, col2)'||CHR(10)||'VALUES ('||
       id||','''||city||''','''||col1||''','''||col2||''');'
  FROM cust_table
 WHERE city = 'San Francisco';
quit;
+EOF
```

This results in a file somefile.sql with the following contents:

```
INSERT INTO cust_table (id, city, col1, col2)
VALUES (1,'San Francisco','C1V1','C2V1');
INSERT INTO cust_table (id, city, col1, col2)
VALUES (4,'San Francisco','C1V4','C2V4');
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't understand why all this union?, i want something more generic, so i don't need to dump all colums names in my code, this is why i used select * in my question, so i want to dump all columns of the table.

Comment: I also got this error when i want to run my script : ORA-00904: col6: invalid identifier

Comment: It's just an illustration - a way to supply a little bit of input to the SELECT statement to show that it works. In your real script, you'll omit that part.

Comment: Where does col6 come from? Did you modify the script I have in my answer to suit your actual table? The example I posted works. Take out the WITH clause, and change/add column names in your SELECT to match your actual table.

Comment: I use this : WITH CUSTOMERS AS 
(SELECT username, city FROM dual)
SELECT 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (username, city)'||CHR(10)||' VALUES ('||username||','''||city||''');'
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE username = 'Julie';